# Issue with sorting in Bars (Spotfire 6.5)

Tags: spotfire

I am faced with this weird issue.
I have designed reports and filtered using Document Properties.
I have a bar graph which has a rule set to show Top N values. Where the N gets controlled using a Input Doc Property.

The funny starts now. The bars are sorted by value. When I open the reports in web player I see the proper set of Top N values. When the intended consumer opens it and changes to his value (S)He sees wrong set of values.

I have defaulted it to Top 3. Which always populates correct bars for both of us. But when we change it to something else it shows wrong results for the user and proper ones for me.

Can someone suggest what the problem might be

Regards,

Rahul S

Comment: Can you elaborate on wrong versus right? Is it just the ordering of the bars or the underlying data? You stated that when we change it to something else it shows wrong results for the user and proper ones for you, are you using the web player to mimic their actions and it's not showing the same results?

Comment: @scsimon Yes. We both are using web player to check the reports. The user has a system which gives him top N items in excel. We are trying to do the same in Spotfire. Data does not have issues as my SQL o/p matches what the user has in excel. When opening in web player my browser on my machine shows me an exact match to the top 10. While the user has top 3 match. Top 4-10 don't match. And this issue is not consistent either. If I ask user to clear cookies, it gets fixed. But then I tested with another user who is logging into server for the first time and he too saw wrong results

Comment: How is the data getting loaded into the dxp? Is it using an information link? If so is it set to cache-able?

Comment: Data is coming from an IL. And the report itself is cached on Server. Do I need to specifically say that for the IL as well

Comment: No. If you cache the IL what that does is pull the data ONCE for that IL and every dxp that uses it will use the cache data instead of pulling the data each time. The catch is, if you make some changes to the data (i.e. the excel or the data base query which returns the data) this won't be reflected until the cache expires on the IL. When you say the report itself is cached on the server, do you mean that you are loading it into the web player memory via scheduled updates?

Comment: Yes. I have scheduled it to refresh. So data gets cached on web player Server.  It gets refreshed daily.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129646/discussion-between-scsimon-and-subro).

Comment: @scsimon Any updates on this? I am still stuck. I havent tried caching the IL as the data is loaded once a day and I refresh the report cache on Server immediately after the ETL has run this way I have latest data.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered scenarios like this where web player users are not seeing what the analysis developer sees. We have had good luck with unchecking the Library Document Property **Remember personalized view for each web client user**.

In Spotfire client, go to Edit > Document Properties > Library tab and you'll see the check box setting, should look like this:

[image: Disable web user personalization]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks I did this and nothing happened. The consumer still sees the wrong set of values. I even asked them to login to portal and navigate to the reports in library rather than directly using the report link. still no use.

Comment: Oh no, sorry to hear this wasn't what you needed. Thank you for the update, though, and I'll be anxious to learn how you resolve this.